# Why is check_password_hash function returning false? Using Flask, SQLite3 and Werkzeug

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to create a basic login function using Flask,  Werkzeug and SQLite.
The users are able to register and a hash of their password is stored in a SQLite database, though when I try to login using the correct password the check_password_hash returns false.

Currently I am comparing the password provided by the user to the relevant hash stored in the SQLite database, which was created using generate_password_hash when user registered.
I have read the Werkzeug documentation, but couldn't find any solutions.

Perhaps this is something related to how generate_password_hash never outputs the same hash twice? Although I thought that check_password_hash was able to work around that?

Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
            with sqlite3.connect("finance.db") as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor() 
                username = request.form.get("username")
                password = request.form.get("password")
                confirm_password = request.form.get("confirm-password")
                hash_value = generate_password_hash(password)
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", (username,))
                valid_username = cur.fetchone()
                
                # Check input and format: Username already taken? Username entered? Password entered? passwords match?
                if valid_username:
                    return ("Username not available")
                if not username:
                    return("Please enter a username")
                elif not password:
                    return("Please enter a password")
                elif not confirm_password:
                    return("Please confirm your password")
                elif password != confirm_password:
                    return ("Passwords do not match")
                else:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,hash) VALUES (?,?)", (username,hash_value))
                    return redirect("/")



@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)
# User login
# Query database for username and hash
        with sqlite3.connect("finance.db") as conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            username_field = request.form.get("username")
            cur.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username_field,))
            username = cur.fetchall()
            cur.execute("SELECT hash FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username_field,))
            pwhash = cur.fetchone()

            # Ensure username exists and password is correct           
            if len(username) != 1 or not check_password_hash(pwhash, request.form.get("password")):
                print(check_password_hash(pwhash, request.form.get("password")))
                return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)
            return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add the code you used to generate the hash.

Comment: Just added it. Let me know if you need to see more.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't see anything obviously wrong.

So... I assume `print(check_password_hash(pwhash, request.form.get("password")))` prints `False`?


Can you also print the values of `pwhash` and `request.form.get("password")`?

Comment: Here you are: ```print(check_password_hash(pwhash, request.form.get("password")))``` prints ```False```
```print(pwhash)``` prints ```('pbkdf2:sha256:150000$AjKdB2Df$838cba14de17eb43bcd7f93dc1eea89fdbeb59c10d422a8bc50e32a04b959018',)``` and
```print(request.form.get("password"))``` prints ```onaj``` , which is the correct password that I entered.

Comment: I am not sure why it is printing false because:
`
>>> from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
>>> check_password_hash("pbkdf2:sha256:150000$AjKdB2Df$838cba14de17eb43bcd7f93dc1eea89fdbeb59c10d422a8bc50e32a04b959018", "onaj")
True
>>>
`

Comment: Aha! Solved it. Syntax error, pwhash` is a tuple because that is what `fetchone()` returns, so it need to be 
`check_password_hash(pwhash[0], request.form.get("password"))`
Thank you so much for the support. It hadn't occurred to me to test the `check_password_hash` function in isolation, doing that made me realise that I am working with a tuple. Cheers. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Solved it. Syntax error, pwhash` is a tuple because that is what fetchone() returns, so it need to be check_password_hash(pwhash[0], request.form.get("password")) Thank you so much for the support. It hadn't occurred to me to test the check_password_hash function in isolation, doing that made me realise that I am working with a tuple. Cheers @JanL. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a sql database or any other db, check the character length you specified. The hashing algorithms return long strings, which can sometimes get truncated when pushed to db, which can give verification errors. So set the password length to a reasonably large character length to avoid errors.